# How can i make my each database field into a public variable in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I got my all database field by doing this query

```
"SHOW  COLUMNS FROM admin"
```

but i am wondering how could i make each of them into a public variable!
and yes these variables will be in a class as i am doing OO PHP.

First, i need to take all field name from my database. Then I need to put them into a variable of a class.

Comment: That's what an array with alphanumeric keys is for. (What are those called again in PHP? In JSON they are objects and in Perl they are hashes). How would your code know to use one of those variables if you add columns? You'd have to change the code.

Comment: So you want dynamic _accessors_ for your class that resembles a database table, and you do not want to update your code when the data source layout changes. I can see a few things that might go wrong with this.

Comment: Does your database user have access to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Comment: Yes have access of INFORMATION_SCHEMA @bassxzero

Comment: You know, if you select records from admin and return them with `PDOStatement::fetchObject`, [each column will be a public variable in the returned objects](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchobject-returnvalues).

Comment: @simbabque if i add columns it will change automatically  as i am using this sql query
"SHOW  COLUMNS FROM admin"

Comment: @Don'tPanic please explain how i use PDOStatement::fetchObject ? i don't understand it :(

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use PDO to connect to database and execute queries:

```
try{
            $db_host = '...';  //  hostname
            $db_name = '...';  //  databasename
            $db_user = '...';  //  username
            $user_pw = '...';  //  password
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_host.";dbname=".$db_name, $db_user, $user_pw, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            //---------------------- QUERY -----------------------
            $sql = "insert your query here";
            //----------------------END QUERY -----------------------

            $data = $pdo->query($sql);
            //the next lines will convert the query results to an array 
            //containing the contents as single variables
            $return = array();
            foreach($data as $row){
                $data = $row[0];
                array_push($return, $row);
            }
            return $return;
        }catch(PDOException $erro){
            echo $erro->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

The `$return` variable will be an array of every row the query returned, and then you can access it as single variables.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without pdo ?

Comment: yes, there is, but PDO is your best option. What is the struggle?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to predefine the column names like this in order to access your database rows as objects.

Assuming you have [established a PDO connection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) `$pdo`, you can execute a select query against a table and [return your results as objects](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) with public property names that correspond to the column names in your table.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM admin');
while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    // each $row is an object with public properties matching the column names
    // so you can do things with $row->column_a, etc.
    // (obviously I don't know your actual column names)
}
```

It is very similar with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php):

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM admin');
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) { // ... }
```

Comment: i don't  have established a PDO connection ! Is there any way to do it without pdo ?

Comment: @Mahmudhasan I edited the answer to show a small example of how to do it with mysqli. It has a fetch object method as well. If you're using the obsolete mysql extension, I can't help you.

Comment: ok, I fetch object ! then it returned all my field name (  id name username email password level). now, how can I make them each one a variable?

Comment: You can't use `$row->username`, `$row->email`, etc.?

Comment: sorry i can't understand your comment :(

Comment: It's okay, I think I'm not understanding what you're asking. Maybe it would help if you could **[edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47269357/edit)** to show an example of how you're wanting to use the result of this?

Comment: First, i need to take all field name from my database.
Then I need to put them into a variable of a class.